# How do I get rid of Rocksmith 2014 audio lag?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

I have Rocksmith 2014 on PC at Steam. I have a latency problem each time I play the guitar. Is there a way to get rid of it?
I've tried messing around with my cable, tried using microphone, tried using alternate options, and there is still nonstop lag.

Comment: What do you mean by "lagg"? Input lag? Audio and picture not syncing properly?

Comment: Im hitting a note , and there is a small delay , but when im trying to play a full song the delay is just unreal (not too much but there is a noticable delay) either in the menu or ingame

Comment: Older version of the game, but the reason should still be relevant: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44222/how-to-eliminate-rocksmith-audio-delay-completely

Comment: Are you playing through a TV or a monitor? TV's typically have processing lag when it comes to games. If you are playing on a TV, check the settings for a 'Game Mode' or 'PC mode' option

Answer (score 1):

Not every delay can be fixed via Rocksmith.

Due to hardware issues, I temporarily put my laptop in place of my desktop. All settings are similar, but the laptop has a slight audio delay that the desktop didn't have. Just like how you described it.

I assume this is caused by some hardware component of the laptop being slower than my desktop's counterpart. I checked every aspect of the USB device's setup. Everything is the same, but the delay still exists.

This isn't something Rocksmith can adjust, as the only calibration the game allows (from memory, it's been a while) is to correct audio-video lag (which in essence exists to get rid of graphical lag)

Comment: I don't know the technical details of the game, but I know from working with true audio interfaces  that older USB ports could have significant lag as the signal went through a software processing layer. The later ones (usb 2 I think) have straightened this out.

Comment: The official cable, itself, operates in a way that is slow and inefficient. While they advertise that you require their cable, any cable should be fine. We sometimes would use standard auxilary for second input. If it comes to it, any cable that has *seperate connections for input and output* should also improve lag considerably.